# how to delete already printed text on terminal screen before printing the next text on rust?

Tags: rust, terminal

I have printed the text using `print!` `print!("Hello world")`now I want to clear the this text before printing the next text `print!("hello rust")`I found this crate [`clear screen`](https://docs.rs/clearscreen/latest/clearscreen/) but this clears the whole terminal instead of the already printed text. I just want to clear the printed text and the not the whole terminal.

Comment: You can try printing as many `\x08` (backspace) characters as length of the current line

Answer (score 0):

You can print a `\x08` or "backspace" character to move the curser back one spot. Or you can use `\r` to move it to the start of the line. Neither option will actually erase characters so you need to print spaces to fill them up.

```rs
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    // print some text
    print!("abcdefgh");
    // Flush, by default input is buffered and only sent at the end of the line. Thus we must flush for the text to appear.
    std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    // Wait 0.5 seconds, this is just to demonstrate the effect.
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs_f32(0.5));
    // Print 8 backspace characters, clearing the line.
    print!("\r{}\r", " ".repeat(8));
}
```

This only works if the line has not yet ended, however, there are ANSII escape codes available to move the cursor up if you have reached the end of the line. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code for more info.

If you want to print the previous line instead use this:

```rs
fn main() {
    // print some garbage, with a line break at the end
    println!("abcdefgh");
    // again just a sleep just to the effect is visible
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs_f32(0.5));
    // move up one then replace all the text with spaces to hide it
    println!("\x1b[1;A{}", " ".repeat(8));
}
```

Note that this is all very terminal specific. These command work differently on windows vs linux and different linux distributions.

Comment: You might want to add that `'\r'` moves the cursor to the left end on the same line. In many cases this is easier than counting characters.

Comment: @thebusybee True, I've found `\r` to be unreliable cross platform

Comment: I did not use it often, but beginning with CP/M and MS-DOS 3.3 over different Windows versions and Linux shells, this is one of the most reliable control character I found. ;-) Of course like its companion `'\n'`. On what platform or with what shell does it not work for you?

Comment: @thebusybee what if I have printed more than one line and I want to go back to the start of the line 1 can I use multiple`\r`  to go back to the left end of the line1

Comment: @SarangDutta You can use `"\x1b[n;A"` to go up `n` lines. Replace n with any number you like.

Comment: No. `'\r'` in the left-most column does not move the cursor at all. It is one of the most simple, not to say primitive, control characters. If you want more control over your output, consider using a library like ncurses.